# MDX query with multiple filters using OR

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following MDX query which I have been asked to extend:

```
    SELECT {} ON COLUMNS,
CROSSJOIN(
    [Waterbody].[Waterbody Code].[Waterbody Code],
    [Waterbody].[Waterbody Name].[Waterbody Name],
    [Waterbody].[Waterbody Type].[Waterbody Type],
    filter([Waterbody].[Waterbody Full Name].allmembers,instr([Waterbody].[Waterbody Full Name].currentmember.member_caption,'Test Waterbody Name')>0)
    )  ON ROWS FROM [Waterbody Data]
```

There is another column called "Waterbody Name" and I need to return the rows where the the given value is in either "Waterbody Full Name" or "Waterbody Name".

I'm handy enough at SQL but this MDX stuff is completely new to me. I spent a large part of yesterday trying different things but got nowhere. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

Just put the members you want to return into a set (noted by curly braces), and that's it. No need for `Filter`:

```
SELECT {} ON COLUMNS,
CROSSJOIN(
    [Waterbody].[Waterbody Code].[Waterbody Code],
    [Waterbody].[Waterbody Name].[Waterbody Name],
    [Waterbody].[Waterbody Type].[Waterbody Type],
    { 
      [Waterbody].[Waterbody Full Name].[Waterbody Full Name],
      [Waterbody].[Waterbody Full Name].[Waterbody Name]
    }
    )  ON ROWS
FROM [Waterbody Data]
```

If you are using the MDX window in SQL Server Management Studio to edit your query, you can drag the members from the list in the left to your script. In this case, depending on cube configuration details, the generated syntax may be slightly different - like containing an ampersand, but both should work. However, using this feature of the the MDX window avoids typos.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but in your example, how does it filter to the specific values? They aren't specified in your example

Comment: +1 spot on as usual ... do you ever use the MDX tool [http://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio](http://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio) ....jst wondering if worth exploring?

Comment: @JohnMc I understood your question to be that you wanted to display just the two members named "Waterbody Full Name" and "Waterbody Name". That is waht this MDX statement does. MDX is not SQL, members (as well as levels, hierarchies, dimensions etc.) are referenced directly, not with string operations normally. If I misunderstood your question, please clarify.

Comment: Hi Frank, sorry if I didn't explain it clearly. I need to modify the MDX query to return the results which match either Waterbody Full Name or Waterbody Name. At present it is only doing it for the former. I'm well aware that it's not SQL, if only it was!

Comment: @JohnMc What do you mean by "match"? I was assuming it means "name equals", as well as that both these members are in the `Waterbody Full Name` hierarchy of the `Waterbody` dimension. Is this the case?

Comment: Hi Frank, yes that's the case. In terms of SQL I'm looking for a "Where [Waterbody Full Name] ='Test Full Name' OR [Waterbody Name]='Test Short Name'